# Out of Memory very quickly with Bitmaps

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains a single Fragment and that Fragment has a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter that pages other Fragments:

```
                                         --> ChildFragment
MyActivity -> HostFragment w ViewPager   --> ChildFragment
                                         --> ChildFragment
```

In the ChildFragment, I use the [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
 library to display a couple of Images. 
On a Nexus S i run out of memory with the infamous

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

very fast, after about 10 Childfragments swiped (about 50-100 bitmaps).
I tried settings all recommended settings to the UIL config, disabled chaching, to no avail. 
I also tried recycling all bitmaps of a Childfragment in onDestroyView, didn't help.

1. Could my setup with the nested fragments have to do with this problem? In another app I only have an Activity with a Viewpager and the Childfragments (without the middle fragment) and I don't have this problem.
2. I checked the Heap size in Eclipses DDMS view, how can the app crash when it still has 45% of its Heap size free? 
   The heap view says: `Heap size 10 MB   Allocated 5,4 MB    Free 4,5 MB`
   How can the the app out of memory like that?

Comment: try using thubnail of images

Comment: are you laoding images by using the `inSampleSize`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/827110

Comment: @Amulya Khare This is all done by the UIL library internally, but I'm pretty sure it does use that.

Comment: maybe you are keeping references to bitmaps. Post your code..

Comment: @user1281750 I already do that as stated in the question.

Comment: Sorry, haven't throughly read the question, maybe this devbytes episode could help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you should use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).  It is to be used for many Fragments and handles saving/restoring their state as you swipe between them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that a Bitmap needs a lot of memory (4 bytes for each pixel) => so a 5MP photo would need 20MB if it's not shrunk.

Read the developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to learn more about shrinking your bitmap to the size you need.

In short, you ask the system to retrieve the bitmap's information without retrieving the bitmap itself. With that information you calculate the inSampleSize (a certain factor to scale it) and ask the system to return the bitmap with that scale.

Comment: As I said I don't load the Bitmaps myself, but I trust the UIL library to use such methods to preserve memory.

Answer (score 0):

this is well known issue in android.refer this. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html